# JQuery-UI Nested Sortable and Scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

All

I have the following code which works fine until you try to scroll on the inner scroll bar:

```
<ul class="meh">
            <li>
                <a href="#">TEXT 1</a>
                <ul class="meh">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">TEXT 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEXT 10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT 10</a></li>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $(".meh").sortable();
            });
        </script>
```

The inner UL will drag after you're done scrolling as can be seen here:

http://jsbin.com/isujuq/2

I have no idea how to solve this problem

Thanks!

Comment: I've narrowed it down a bit. I now know it is not related to the the fact that there are nested sortable items, but more to the fact that scrolling seems to be triggering the drag event of the sortable item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

Went through a bit of documentation and bumped into the "cancel" option of sortable().

If you add a wrapper, such as a "div" element and make that overflow:scroll instead, you can use that same div as your cancel selector, as follows:

```
$(".meh").each(function(){
    $(this).sortable({cancel: ".scrollable"});
});
```